# ListView.builder showing free space if appbar is null

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My app showing an empty space for listview builder if app bar is null and no space if we add appbar. 
Why it is showing space here? and How to solve this issue?

I tried to set margin as `-MediaQuery.of(context).padding.toptop` padding height but it also make error app not worked. How to set ***-*** value for margin i am android java developer for this types of issue i was solving by added `-MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top` margin

```
class BizCart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BizCartState createState() => _BizCartState();
}

class _BizCartState extends State<BizCart> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body:Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          GradientAppBar(),
          Expanded(child:Container(


              child:ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 31,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index)
                  {
                    return CartItemCard();
                  })
          ), )

        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Code with out appBar
[image]
[image: Flutter Empty space if appBar is null]
Code with appBar
[image: Flutter developer midhilaj]

Comment: It most likely problem with your `GradientAppBar`. If possible can you add it.

Comment: Problem solved check my answer below using  MediaQuery.removePadding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 MediaQuery.removePadding(
                  removeTop: true,
                  context: context, child: ListView.builder(

                  itemCount: 31,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index)
                  {
                    return CartItemCard();
                  }))


          ), )
```

[Flutter removePadding](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14842#issuecomment-371344881)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
class BizCart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BizCartState createState() => _BizCartState();
}

class _BizCartState extends State<BizCart> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: GradientAppBar(
        gradient: LinearGradient(colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue]),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 31,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return CartItemCard();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```